# Найти длину самой длинной последовательности двоичного файла

Tags: java, файлы

**Как звучит само задание:**
Найти длину самой длинной последовательности двоичного файла которая состоит из байтов со значением 0.

**Слова преподавателя:**
К примеру:
Если у Вас есть двоичной файл, байт которого выглядят так:
1 2 0 0 0 14 15 16 0 0 0 0 0 10 12 14 15 0 12
То длина самой длинной последовательности, состоящий из байтов со значением 0 - 5

Не могу понять, что именно от меня хотят, заранее спасибо!
Пишу на Java, выполняю ввод через BufferedReader, не думаю, что это столь важно, но все же упомяну.

```
import java.io.*;

public class LongestZeroSequenceLength {
    long longestZeroSequenceLength(String filename) throws IOException {
        int result = 0;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int count = 0;
            int readed = -1;
            while((readed = fis.read(buf)) != -1){
                for(int i = 0;i < readed;i++){
                    System.out.println(buf[i]);
                    if(buf[i] == 0){
                        count++;
                    } else{
                        if(result < count){
                            result = count;
                            count = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  result;
    }
}
```

Comment: _что именно от меня хотят_, а кто хотят, у них нельзя спросить?

Comment: Задание нужное для лабараторной на завтра.

Comment: Хорошо, а что не  понятно в задании?

Comment: Как найти байт двоичного файла

Comment: @Fetix все же не понятно, почему бы не спросить у преподавателя, а не задаваться вопросами в последний день. Спросите у одногруппников тогда. А вообще судя по условию задачи, то вам просто надо [прочитать](https://funnelgarden.com/java_read_file/) в массив байт, файл. И просто найти самую длинную последовательность 0. В чем конкретно проблема? "_По словам преподавателя_" вообще в ступор вводит.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что в файле будет некая последовательность по типу:  
1 2 0 0 0 14 15 16 0 0 0 0 0 10 12 14 15 0 12  
?

Comment: @Fetix в файле будут всякие непонятные символы. Если он конечно бинарный. А вот если прочитать его в массив байтов, то увидите по идее 1 2 0 (Коды по таблице ASCII непонятных символов в файле) и т.д.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков я написал код, что скажите?

Comment: @Fetix вы попробуйте запустить и сами проверьте. Через hex редактор можете посмотреть значения байт в файле и сравнить со своим результатом. Ну а так с первого взгляда вроде нормально все)

Comment: @Fetix добавьте после цикла еще одну проверку на максимум или уберите `else` и проверяйте в цикле на максимум каждую итерацию.

Answer (score -2):

Вот код, ***не*** решающий Вашу проблему:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(getЧислоПоследовательныхБайтов("file"));
    }
    
    public static int getЧислоПоследовательныхБайтов(String filepath)
    {
        int result = 0;
        File file = new File(filepath);
        
        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file))
        {
            int count = 0;
            byte[] buf = new byte[(int)file.length()];
            fis.read(buf);
            fis.close();
            
            for(int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++)
            {
                if(buf[i] >= 0 && buf[i] <= 5)
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else if(count != 0)
                {
                    if(count > result)
                    {
                        result = count;
                    }
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
            if(count > result)
            {
                result = count;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: По заданию требуется найти максимальную длину последовательности, а у вас фиг знает, что. Если в конце файла будет байт `< 0 || > 5`, то ответ будет 0. Смысл тогда алгоритма?

Comment: да, действительно. исправил код

Comment: Да вроде рабочий код), но у автора в вопроса код намного эффективней.

Comment: да, вижу. только по условию нужно посчитать длину последовательности байтов от 0 до 5. следовательно не if(buf[i] == 0), а if(buf[i] >= 0 && buf[i] <= 5) =)

Comment: @ПавелЕриков что скажите насчет такого кода? цикл всего один, а у автора вопроса два.

Comment: По условию "_То длина самой длинной последовательности, состоящий из байтов со значением 0 - 5_" То есть со значение 0, потом тире,  которое означает, что длина последовательности из нулей равна 5. А не промежуток от 0 до 5. И у автора 2 цикла только потому, что он считывает по 1024 байта, а у вас весь файл сразу. Если файл достаточно большой, то лучше по 1024 байта считывать, а не весь.

Comment: а-а... извиняюсь уже в который раз) не буду больше мучать этот вопрос и Вас))

Comment: @ПавелЕриков
Собственно немного передалал свой код, скачал бинарный файл, все считает, все отлично. Можете посмотреть, что вышло

Comment: @doodocina исправил, можете посмотреть